# Extend lower range

Tags: technique, voice, vocal-range

I'm 14 years old my vocal range is it may sound crazy for 14 year old but B1 to about C5 I would like to extend my lower range can anyone help?

Comment: What type of singer are you?

Comment: Why do you want to extend your lower range? If your specs are correct, you already reach lower than basically all Western literature. That's like a painter who wants to be able to hold an even larger brush. You should focus on actually working with what you have rather than putting it on hold for something else. It's certainly good that you are not lacking in the lower range department, but singing is not a range competition.

Comment: The kind with a pretty good range in the morning I can go lower to about G#1